# Convert Dataframe to a Dictionary with List Values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a **Dataframe df** :

```
Label1    Label2        Label3
key1      col1value1    col2value1
key2      col1value2    col2value2
key3      col1value3    col2value3


dict1 = df.set_index('Label1').to_dict()
```

This works when we have 2 columns..

**Expected Output:**

```
my_dict = {key1: [col1value1,col2value1] , key2: [ col1value2,col2value2] , key3:[col1value3,col2value3] }
```

Can I use `to_dict` on Dataframe **df** to have a key with **2 other columns** as **values** in form of **list** ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use a dictionary comprehension and iterrows:

```
print {key:row.tolist() for key,row in df.set_index('Label1').iterrows()}

{'key3': ['col1value3', 'col2value3'],
 'key2': ['col1value2', 'col2value2'], 
 'key1': ['col1value1', 'col2value1']}
```

Also, I think the following will work too:

```
df = df.set_index('Label1')
print df.T.to_dict(outtype='list')

{'key3': ['col1value3', 'col2value3'],
 'key2': ['col1value2', 'col2value2'],
 'key1': ['col1value1', 'col2value1']}
```

Update as of fall 2017; `outtype` is no longer the keyword argument. Use orient instead:

```
In [11]: df.T.to_dict(orient='list')
Out[11]: 
{'key1': ['col1value1', 'col2value1'],
 'key2': ['col1value2', 'col2value2'],
 'key3': ['col1value3', 'col2value3']}
```

Comment: Could you explain the 2nd approach , i did not understand . What does "T" do?

Comment: T transposes the dataframe.

Comment: Great approach using `T`, didn't even realize that would work thank you.