# Merge multiple columns into one column list with [key:value] combination in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let me preface this question by noting that the combined column is not a dictionary. The resulting dataframe has square brackets within the 'combined' column - so it appears like a list within the dataframe int he format [key1:value1, key2:value2, etc].

I'm trying to convert my dataframe from this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'apples':['red','green','yellow'], 'quantity':
[1,2,3],'tasteFactor':['yum','yum','yuck']})

   apples  quantity tasteFactor
0     red         1         yum
1   green         2         yum
2  yellow         3        yuck
```

To this format, which is combining keys with values in each row into a new column:

```
   apples  quantity tasteFactor  combined
0     red         1         yum  ['apples':'red','quantity':'1','tastefactor':'yum']
1   green         2         yum  ['apples':'green','quantity':'2','tastefactor':'yum']
2  yellow         3        yuck  ['apples':'yellow','quantity':'3','tastefactor':'yuck']
```

Tried to turn the dataframe into a dictionary per row, but got stuck converting that into a list.

```
test['combined'] = test.to_dict(orient='records')
```

The resulting new column doesn't need to be an actual list type. It could be a string.

Previously asked this question here but wanted to clarify the question in the title in this question.
[How to Create a List from a Dictionary within a DataFrame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670751/how-to-create-a-list-from-a-dictionary-within-a-dataframe-in-python)

Found the following closely related questions and tried derivations of them which gets me half the way but can't seem to get exactly the right format.

- [Combine columns in a Pandas DataFrame to a column of lists in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145148/combine-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-column-of-lists-in-a-dataframe)
- [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)
- [Convert Dataframe to a Dictionary with List Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509047/convert-dataframe-to-a-dictionary-with-list-values)
- [How to create a dictionary of key : column_name and value : unique values in column in python from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105375/how-to-create-a-dictionary-of-key-column-name-and-value-unique-values-in-col)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by using the apply method of pandas dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'apples':['red','green','yellow'], 'quantity':
[1,2,3],'tasteFactor':['yum','yum','yuck']})

col_names = df.columns

def func(row):
    global col_names
    list_ = [str(b)+':'+str(a) for a,b in zip(row,col_names.values.tolist())]
    return list_

x = list(map(func, df.values.tolist()))
df.loc[:,'combined'] = pd.Series(x)
# df
#    apples  quantity tasteFactor                                       combined
# 0     red         1         yum      [apples:red, quantity:1, tasteFactor:yum]
# 1   green         2         yum    [apples:green, quantity:2, tasteFactor:yum]
# 2  yellow         3        yuck  [apples:yellow, quantity:3, tasteFactor:yuck]
```

Comment: I ran this code... and got back
   apples  quantity tasteFactor                          combined
    0     red         1         yum                 (a, p, p, l, e, s)
1   green         2         yum           (q, u, a, n, t, i, t, y)
2  yellow         3        yuck  (t, a, s, t, e, F, a, c, t, o, r)

Comment: Edited. Please check

Comment: Thanks! Added single quotes to make it list_ = ['\''+str(b)+'\': \''+str(a)+'\'' for a,b in zip(row,col_names.values.tolist())]

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned *The resulting new column doesn't need to be an actual list type.*

```
di=test.T.to_dict()
test['Mapper']=test.index
test.Mapper.map(di)
test.assign(combined=test.Mapper.map(di)).drop('Mapper',1)


Out[493]: 
   apples  quantity tasteFactor                                           combined
0     red         1         yum  {'apples': 'red', 'quantity': 1, 'tasteFactor'...
1   green         2         yum  {'apples': 'green', 'quantity': 2, 'tasteFacto...
2  yellow         3        yuck  {'apples': 'yellow', 'quantity': 3, 'tasteFact...
```

EDIT:

```
di=test.T.to_dict()
test['Mapper']=test.index
test.Mapper.map(di)
test=test.assign(combined=test.Mapper.map(di).astype(str)).drop('Mapper',1)
test=test.combined.str.replace('{','[').str.replace('}',']')


test.combined[0]
Out[511]: "['apples': 'red', 'quantity': 1, 'tasteFactor': 'yum']"
```

Comment: Yes, but was looking for the square bracket format and it could be a string type.

Comment: @sweetnlow give me one sec

Comment: @sweetnlow Edited , just using `str.replace`